# Simple jquery Slideshow- Positioning wrong when navigate fwd more that a single slide

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, slideshow, margin

Here is my javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //variables
    var noOfSlides = 8;
    var slideWidth = 702;
    // Skip to a slide in sequence
    function goToSlide (number) {
        marginValue = ((-slideWidth * number) );
        $('#slide_inner_wrapper').stop().animate({'left': marginValue }, {duration: 1000});
    }
    $('#slide_inner_wrapper').width(noOfSlides * slideWidth) + 135; //Initial sizing of wrapper

    // Listeners
    $('.marker').bind('click', function() {
        number = parseInt($(this).attr('id').split('-').slice(1));
        $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass('current');
        $(this).parent().addClass('current');
        goToSlide(number);
    });
});
```

I've created a fiddle, so you can see my problem:
http://jsfiddle.net/jXVR2/1/

You may have to resize the window slightly...but you can see what I am trying to achieve hopefully! It's a timeline that animates to a specific year when clicked on.

If you click the individual years at the top, the corresponding slide should appear in the centre of the view. This works fine if you load it up then click through from 2005 one slide at a time, however as soon as you skip multiple slides, it jumps off position? I thought this was to do with the margin value, but it's not- the calculations are fine. I have spent hours looking at it and can't crack it...Could it be to do with positioning? I have spent the last hour fiddling with this with no solution :(

Any help much appreciated! My first post on here, so please be kind! Thanks :)

Comment: Your slide width does not match the amount you offset your div by.

Comment: Thanks Asad, but I'm not quite sure I understand- the div is offset by a multiple of the slide width, I don't think this is related to the problem. If you know that this is definitely it, could you be a bit more specific, as I can't see it!

Comment: Just to update- It's definitely not the slide width @Asad.

Comment: It works perfectly when I remove the jquery animate method and replace it by the css method...

Comment: I must have been wrong, only took a cursory look. Any luck figuring it out btw?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I got from the jsfiddle, the problem arise due to the hashtags of the `<a href="#2005">` tags.

When you click on the links, the focus goes to the hashtag and hence the animation goes offkey.

If you don't need the hashtags, you can replace it to simply `<a href="#">`.

And if you need the hashtags, use `return false` at the end of the click function, i.e.

```
$('.marker').bind('click', function() {
    number = parseInt($(this).attr('id').split('-').slice(1));
    $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass('current');
    $(this).parent().addClass('current');
    goToSlide(number);
    return false;
});
```

Comment: a small edit in your jsfiddle...you should use... $('#slide_inner_wrapper').width(noOfSlides * slideWidth+ 135)...must have been a typo I think...

Comment: Argh, thanks for that! Really appreciate it, knew it would be something simple, but unexpected! xD Cheers!